# Getting an image to my html from my controller in angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

I cant seem to get the image to show up. How exactly would I write this to get it in my html from my controller using angular.js? I am using a ui-router also

The title shows up, but not the image.

Controller:

```
angular
.module('app')
    .controller('aboutCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.title = "About",
        $scope.image = "images/myimage.jpg";
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="center">{{title}}</h3>
<figure class="image">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" >               
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't passed reference of controller. try this.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="aboutCtrl">

   <h3 class="center">{{title}}</h3>
   <figure class="image">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" >               
   </figure>

 <div>
```